# How to solve overwritten port forwarding in virtualbox via vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, portforwarding

I have

- host: Windows
- guest: Unix system
- Virtualization: Vagrant + VirtualBox

I have configuration for ports forwarding in `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 8011, host: 80, host_ip: '127.0.0.111'
config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 8022, host: 80, host_ip: '127.0.0.222'
```

Due to reason there is the same port on the host side (but with different IP addresses) there the same name used in port forwarding table in VirtualBox and the last one overwrites previous one.

In this example we have name "tcp80".

Is there any option to provide name or make it unique?

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking is called `auto_correct`

```
config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 8011, host: 80, host_ip: '127.0.0.111', auto_correct: true
config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 8022, host: 80, host_ip: '127.0.0.222', auto_correct: true
```

from [vagrant doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html)

> It is common when running multiple Vagrant machines to unknowingly create forwarded port definitions that collide with each other (two separate Vagrant projects forwarded to port 8080, for example). Vagrant includes built-in mechanism to detect this and correct it, automatically.

Comment: the same error. Actually, this is an expected behavior. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7905

Answer (score 0):

`id` option can be added like this `id: '8ob6tri7v6'`, but...
Unfortunately, this is an expected behavior. I made an issue in the bug tracker on GitHub.

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7905